# How to automatically click on open file button running VBA procedure

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, sap-gui

I am looking for a way to click on a button 'open file'.

I wrote an Excel VBA macro that connects with SAP module. What it should do is to add a file as an attachment in SAP. As a result I get pop-up window, just a standard Windows "open file" window to get the "file name" field and "open file" button.

My question is how to automatically insert a file name (always known) and click on that "open file" button?

I tried `sendkeys` from within Excel VBA, but it turns out that once the "open file" window pops up the whole Sub routine stops.

I know I need Winapi to do this.

Comment: Please post your existing code so people can understand what you have achieved and what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do a `DoEvents` to allow the keys to be processed by SAP.

Quoting from VBA help:

> **DoEvents Function**
>
> Yields execution so that the operating system can process other
>   events.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> ```
> DoEvents( )
> ```
>
> *Remarks*
>
> The DoEvents function returns an Integer representing the number of
>   open forms in stand-alone versions of Visual Basic, such as Visual
>   Basic, Professional Edition. DoEvents returns zero in all other
>   applications.
>
> DoEvents passes control to the operating system. Control is returned
>   after the operating system has finished processing the events in its
>   queue and all keys in the SendKeys queue have been sent.
>
> DoEvents is most useful for simple things like allowing a user to
>   cancel a process after it has started, for example a search for a
>   file. For long-running processes, yielding the processor is better
>   accomplished by using a Timer or delegating the task to an ActiveX EXE
>   component.. In the latter case, the task can continue completely
>   independent of your application, and the operating system takes case
>   of multitasking and time slicing.
>
> Caution   Any time you temporarily yield the processor within an event
>   procedure, make sure the procedure is not executed again from a
>   different part of your code before the first call returns; this could
>   cause unpredictable results. In addition, do not use DoEvents if other
>   applications could possibly interact with your procedure in unforeseen
>   ways during the time you have yielded control.

Comment: It was actually VB6's help from Oct 2001 MSDN.